# SSH: display warning when using (deprecated) ssh-dss key

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssh

With the [7.0 release, OpenSSH disabled ssh-dss keys](https://www.gentoo.org/support/news-items/2015-08-13-openssh-weak-keys.html). The not-so-recommended workaround is to explicitly re-add DSA key support to `.ssh/config`, which will eventually be dropped by a later OpenSSH version:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

As I have deployed my DSA key to countless machines (and I do not have a full list of them, as `known_hosts` is hashed), I have to replace the old public user key whenever I encounter it on login.

**Is it possible to make the OpenSSH client display a warning when I log in with an ssh-dss key?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special mechanism in `ssh` to notify you that you use some key. It works or fails.

## Differentiate the keys using passphrase

Only other idea that comes to my mind is differentiate between the keys using *passphrase*.

For example, have the RSA keys in ssh-agent or without passphrase and the DSA one with passphrase (and not in ssh-agent). It might *warn* you with passphrase prompt.

## Not to use them

The easiest thing is *not* to add the above line into `ssh_config` and then you will see when you can't connect. Then you can use the options on command line for individual connections:

```
ssh -oPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss host
```

Comment: The problem with disabling DSA globally is that I will fallback to password logins, which is not a very suggesting symptom for "DSA key deployed". However, your "Passphrase" approach works. Can you please put it as your primary answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Updated the answer. Glad to help.